# depth_image_proc couldn't find executable

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, node, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey :-)

I'm struggeling with the following problem:

**System**:

- Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit
- ROS Kinetic (Desktop-Full) installed out of the repository via "apt install"

**What I did:**

- Recorded a stream from Lenovo Phab2 (Tango Pointcloud) with all topics into an rosbag file. So far so good :-)

**What I want to achieve:**

- Using the **depth_image_proc** package to join the information of the rgb-camera and the pointcloud-data with the node **depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb**.

i am allowed to run a command like this without any troubles :

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd record.bag /tango/camera/color_1/image_rect
```

In my understanding i should be allowed to replace pcl_ros (package) and bag_to_pcd (node) with depth_image_proc (package) and point_cloud_xyzrgb (node).

But already running this command will prompt into an error:

```
rosrun depth_image_proc point_cloud_xyzrgb 

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named point_cloud_xyzrgb below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/depth_image_proc
```

Investigations:

entering

```
rosrun pcl_ros + TAB
```

will show me the available nodes for pcl_ros. This mechanism is also not working with depth_image_proc. What could be wrong with the environment or am i doing something essentially wrong ? oO

thanks in advance and best regards

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279941/depth_image_proc-couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
Quick check: do you have `depth_image_proc` installed? What is the output of `dpkg -l | grep depth-image-proc`?

**Comment by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on 2018-01-16**:
output:

*ii  ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc                  1.12.22-0xenial-20180105-150342-0800                     amd64        Contains nodelets for processing depth images such as those produced by OpenNI camera.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But already running this command will prompt into an error:

> ```
> $ rosrun depth_image_proc point_cloud_xyzrgb
> ```

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named point_cloud_xyzrgb below /opt/ros/kinetic/share/depth_image_proc
```

This is normal: `depth_image_proc` does not provide any nodes (ie: binaries), but only nodelets (ie: libraries). The [wiki page on `depth_image_proc`](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) also mentions that:

> Contains nodelets for processing depth images such as those produced by OpenNI camera.

You cannot run nodelets using `rosrun`, they can only be loaded into a nodelet manager.

See [wiki/nodelets](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) for more info on nodelets, and see [wiki/nodelets/Running a nodelet](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet) for a tutorial on the basics of running a nodelet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markovicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/33312/markovicho/) on 2018-01-16**:
thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-16**:
No problem.

Note that instead of starting your own nodelet manager, you'll probably want to reuse the manager that is already used by the Tango 'driver' (provided it uses/is a nodelet).

If you start a new one, you'll lose the zero-copy advantages.

**Comment by [bigbellmercy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40244/bigbellmercy/) on 2020-08-28**:
It's very clear answer:

> You cannot run nodelets using rosrun, they can only be loaded into a nodelet manager.